# Prove: All integers are rational numbers, some integers are power of n therefore some rational numbers are power of n

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

How to do the above question? Is this a question related to relations or function? And I would be really grateful if I can just get a hint to do this one

Comment: What is it exactly that we're supposed to prove?  Just that *"some rational numbers are a power of n"?*  If so, then why is the proof in your title not sufficient?

Comment: Try to draw a Venn diagram, with the sets integers, rationals and "numbers that are powers of $n$". If you draw it properly, then you can see why this is the case, at least graphically (The proposition you ask for is very basic, I cannot think of a more abstract proof).